# How to filter 3D array with a 2D mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masking

I have a `(m,n,3)` array `data` and I want to filter its values with a `(m,n)` mask to receive a `(x,3)` `output` array.

The code below works, but how can I replace the for loop with a more efficient alternative?

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
    [[11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19]],
    [[21, 22, 13], [24, 25, 26], [27, 28, 29]],
    [[31, 32, 33], [34, 35, 36], [37, 38, 39]],
])
mask = np.array([
    [False, False, True],
    [False, True, False],
    [True, True, False],
])

output = []
for i in range(len(mask)):
    for j in range(len(mask[i])):
        if mask[i][j] == True:
            output.append(data[i][j])
output = np.array(output)
```

The expected output is

```
np.array([[17, 18, 19], [24, 25, 26], [31, 32, 33], [34, 35, 36]])
```

Comment: `data[mask]`? Am I missing something?

Comment: @SayandipDutta yes that's it. I feel kind of stuipid now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
    [[11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19]],
    [[21, 22, 13], [24, 25, 26], [27, 28, 29]],
    [[31, 32, 33], [34, 35, 36], [37, 38, 39]],
])
mask = np.array([
    [False, False, True],
    [False, True, False],
    [True, True, False],
])

output = data[mask]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).